# wso2 esb console localization

Tags: localization, wso2

I'd like to translate the management console to localized language. I've try to follow the instructions from http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes/ as a starting point, cause I think that should be in the same theory. But this didn't work, and cause an exception when entering the site.

I see the document is pretty old (2011), is this not work anymore? or the procedure has been changed?

Edit:
sorry, forgot to mention, I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you have mentioned, above link is outdated. However, the concept is same in new versions as well. Keeping an extracted jar file in the plugins directory will no longer work since we have disabled that along the way as a security fix.

Herewith I have given [1]. the latest documentation of "Customizing the Management Console" of the WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus. You can use it as a starting point.

If you need further help regarding this issue, please let me know.

Thanks,

Upul

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Customizing+the+Management+Console